# Hash table with "Time To Live" elements

Tags: c++, hash-map, timer, server

Recently, I got a very interesting task: to realize the hash table that works in multi-process server in common memory, each element of which must have a TTL property. It was suggested to implement the TTL, as an additional process that walks through the table every second and corrects the TTLs of elements. I think this solution is not enough elegant.

There is another way to realize this feature: while inserting and deleting check the TTL of handling element. This way also has a disadvantages: bigger worst time indexing, because it must shift some elements, non-unquet time in each process. But, I think it is more elegant, because it is only needed to check necessary elements.

Other limitations:

1. hashtable works in common memory (Unix shared memory in core).

From 1st point follows

2. Fixed size (N lines)
3. Method "open addressing"

I think it is a very interesting task, so I decided to share with you my realization:

```
//-----------------------------------------
typedef   int32_t ht_key_t;
typedef   int32_t ht_val_t;
typedef  uint32_t hash_t;

typedef struct hashtable_record
{ ht_key_t  key;
  ht_val_t  val;
    time_t  ttl;
} ht_rec;
//-----------------------------------------
typedef struct hashtable_line
{ bool    busy;
  ht_rec  data;
} ht_line;
//-----------------------------------------
typedef struct hash_table
{ char    *shmemory;
  size_t   shm_size;
  size_t   lines_count;
  ht_line *lines;
  //------------------------
#ifdef _LOCK
  mysem_t  ln_semid;
  mysem_t  tb_semid;
  myshm_t  tb_shmid;
#endif // _LOCK
  //------------------------
} hashtable;
//-----------------------------------------
#define TIME_EPS 0.01
/* Relative TTL to absolute TTL (in seconds) */
time_t  ttl_converted (int32_t ttl)
{ return (time (NULL) + ttl); }
bool    ttl_completed (time_t  ttl)
{ return (difftime (time (NULL), ttl) > TIME_EPS); }
//-----------------------------------------
void  hashtable_init (hashtable *ht, size_t lines_count, size_t shm_size);
void  hashtable_free (hashtable *ht);
//-----------------------------------------
static hash_t  hash (ht_key_t key);
static hash_t  hashtable_walk (hashtable *ht, ht_rec *data,
                               hash_t he, bool isget)
{
  hash_t h = he, h_ret = h;
  //-----------------------------------------    
  /* walk through the open addressing */
  while ( (h < ht->lines_count) && ht->lines[h].busy )
  {
    hash_t hn = hash (ht->lines[h + 1U].data.key) % ht->lines_count;
    /* if there is a competed ttl */
    if ( ttl_completed (ht->lines[h].data.ttl) )
    {    
      /* if there is no element in open addressing */
      if ( ((h + 1U) >= ht->lines_count) || !ht->lines[h + 1U].busy
          || ((h + 1U) == hn)
      /* or insert here if the next element's hash greater the current */
          || ((he < hn) && !isget) )
      { ht->lines[h].busy = false;
        h_ret = h;
        break;
      } /* found the needed number - to finish */

      hash_t hc = ++h;
      /* while open addressing: index of next element greater then its hash */
      while ( (h < ht->lines_count) && ht->lines[h].busy && (h > hn) )
      { hn = hash (ht->lines[++h].data.key) % ht->lines_count; }

      /* put together the next and prev elements */
      memmove (&ht->lines[hc - 1U], &ht->lines[hc], (h - hc) * sizeof (ht_line));

      ht->lines[h - 1U].busy = false;
      h = hc;
    }
    else if ( ht->lines[h].data.key == data->key )
    {
      h_ret = h;
      break;
    }
    else if ( he < h )
    {
      /* move apart records */
      hash_t hc = h;
      while ( (h < ht->lines_count) && ht->lines[h].busy )
      {
        if ( ttl_completed (ht->lines[h].data.ttl) )
        { ht->lines[h].busy = false;
          break;
        }
        ++h;
      }

      if ( h >= ht->lines_count )
      { break; }

      /* moving apart records */
      memmove (&ht->lines[hc + 1U], &ht->lines[hc], (h - hc) * sizeof (ht_line));
      ht->lines[hc].busy = false;

      h_ret = hc;
      break;
    }

    ++h; h_ret = h;
  } // end while
  //-----------------------------------------
  return h_ret;
}
//-----------------------------------------
bool  hashtable_get (hashtable *ht, ht_rec *data)
{
#ifdef _LOCK
  mysem_lock (ht->tb_semid, 0);
#endif // _LOCK    
  hash_t he = hash (data->key) % ht->lines_count;
  //-----------------------------------------
  hash_t h = hashtable_walk (ht, data, he, true);
  if ( (h < ht->lines_count) && ht->lines[h].busy
      && (ht->lines[h].data.key == data->key) )
  {
    *data = ht->lines[h].data;
  }
  else { h = ht->lines_count; }
  //-----------------------------------------
#ifdef _LOCK
  mysem_unlock (ht->tb_semid, 0);
#endif // _LOCK
  //-----------------------------------------
  return (h == ht->lines_count);
}
bool  hashtable_set (hashtable *ht, ht_rec *data)
{
#ifdef _LOCK
  mysem_lock (ht->tb_semid, 0);
#endif // _LOCK    
  hash_t he = hash (data->key) % ht->lines_count;
  //-----------------------------------------
  hash_t h = hashtable_walk (ht, data, he, false);
  if ( (h < ht->lines_count) && (!ht->lines[h].busy
    || (ht->lines[h].data.key == data->key)) )
  {
    ht->lines[h].data = *data;
    ht->lines[h].busy = true;
  }
  else h = ht->lines_count;
  //-----------------------------------------    
#ifdef _LOCK
  mysem_unlock (ht->tb_semid, 0);
#endif // _LOCK
  //-----------------------------------------
  return (h == ht->lines_count);
}
//-----------------------------------------
#ifdef _DEBUG_HASH
void  hashtable_print_debug (hashtable *ht, FILE *f)
{
  fprintf (f, "\n");
  for ( size_t i = 0U; i < ht->lines_count; ++i )
  {
    fprintf (f, "%3u hash=%2d  %s key=%2d ttl=% 3.2lf val=%d\n", i,
             (ht->lines[i].busy ? hash (ht->lines[i].data.key) % ht->lines_count : -1),
             (ht->lines[i].busy ? "Busy" : "Free"),
             ht->lines[i].data.key,
             !ht->lines[i].data.ttl ? 0. : difftime (time (NULL), ht->lines[i].data.ttl),
             ht->lines[i].data.val);
  }
  return;
}
#endif // _DEBUG_HASH
//------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

**C++ is not C**

Your code is very C - and very excessively brief and hard to follow. Let's C++ify it up. `hashtable` should be a `class` with member functions:

```
class Hashtable
{
public:
    struct rec {
        int32_t key;
        int32_t value;
        time_t ttl;
    };

    Hashtable(size_t lines_count, size_t shm_size);

    rec* find(int32_t key) const;
    bool insert(const rec& elem);
    // etc.

private:
    // whatever members as appropriate
};
```

This way, rather than your users having to deal with all these free functions (especially `_init()`), we can use this like a normal C++ container. Furthermore, if you make the important members private, your users can mess your container up accidentally - they just won't have access.

In that vein, prefer

```
static constexpr double TIME_EPSILON = 0.01;
```

to:

```
#define TIME_EPS 0.01
```

both for the better name (see below), and that generally avoiding macros is a good thing.

**Naming**

Characters are NOT at a premium. Your code will not run slower if you spend the time to write out variables names in a way that readers will understand. For instance, I have no idea what your `he` and `h` and `ht` mean in your `get()` function - where hashtable search is actually a really straightforward algorithm.

You want to provide names that are meaningful. That any other programmer can come to your code later and understand what is going on. Or even, that you coming back 6 months later can understand.

**Spacing**

There's a lot of different conventions for spacing and brace placement in C++. But this one is not good:

```
time_t  ttl_converted (int32_t ttl)
{ return (time (NULL) + ttl); }
```

I'd highly recommend either:

```
time_t ttl_converted(int32_t ttl) {
    return (time(NULL) + ttl);
}
```

or:

```
time_t ttl_converted(int32_t ttl)
{
    return (time(NULL) + ttl);
}
```

Either way, no space between function name and parentheses, no code on same line as opening brace. It's *incredibly* hard to read. And no run on `else` statements like:

```
else h = ht->lines_count;
```

Prefer:

```
else {
    h = ht->lines_count;
}
```

If you always use braces, you won't run into issues if you ever add a second line to your code blocks.

Also, one statement per line! Strongly prefer:

```
++h;
h_ret = h;
```

To:

```
++h; h_ret = h;
```

Though you can write both on the same line in a readable way:

```
h_ret = ++h;
```

**walk**

I don't know what `hashtable_walk()` is doing. It's the bulk of your code, but I can't follow it in the slightest. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you, very much. Spacing and naming is my big problem. Definitely I have chosen incorrect tag - my code is in pure C. It is, because Unix-API is in pure C and, if C++ code interacts with it, IMHO, it looks unnatural. `hashtable_walk()` called so, because it "walks through the hashtable", search for the exact element/place to set or get with correcting the watched ttls and removing completed lines in the hashtable. `walk` takes into account the open addressing - that's because it is so complicated. It was that I wanted to show.